# How to notify the admin a user's birthdate is today in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have  have a model user, and a user can be an ADMIN in ruby on rails 3

the user's table includes

```
  t.boolean :admin,              :default => false
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :department
  t.string :username
  t.datetime :birthdate 
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
```

my question is how do i display or notify the admin that today is a user's birthday 
 i would love if there could be a model,controller and the view inclusive in the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok you already have the model, the User that is. I would just add a method that will tell us whether the user's birthday is today or not:

```
class User
  def birthday_today?
    birthday == Date.today?
  end
end
```

then in the controller, let's say you want to display this on the index page. I will presume that you have your own authentication solution, so let's say a call to current_user will give use the user that is now logged in

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @display_honourees = current_user.admin?
    @honourees = User.all.find_all {|u| u.birthday_today? }
  end
end
```

there, we have all the data we need. Now let's display them:

```
<html>
  ...
  <% if @display_honourees %>
    <ul>
      <% @honourees.each do |honouree| %>
        <li>It's <%= honouree.username %>'s birthday today! Make a party!</li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  ...
</html>
```

Does this do what you need?

Comment: Actually on second thought I think it would be much more optimal to skip the model method and let the db do the lookup for you. Then you would call @honourees = User.where(:birthday => Date.today). That should be better. If you have a lot of users, don't forget to index the birthday to speed up the lookup even further.

Comment: Or maybe even better add a scope to User "scope honourees, lambda{ where(:birthday => Date.today) }" so that the model does the work of the model and then call "@honourees = User.honourees" from the controller.

Comment: also, `today?` is an instance method, not a class method, so it'd just be `birthday.today?`